# Problems of connections with we3.providers

Tags: web3js, testnets, ropsten, connections, web3-providers

I'm using the web3 API and i'm defining the web3 instance, setting a provider like this:

```
if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
  web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
  web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
}
```

But alot of times i have problems with connection, i'm working whit the Ropsten testnet and i'm only using this for test and to learn about Dapps. What is a good alternative for solve this problems of connection? Maybe infura? or exist there some tips to solve it?

Comment: you could use solidity browser to check the connection with your local node if it connects all is ok otherwise check you local settings (node port, is rpc on, firewall etc..)

Comment: the connection maybe is not the problem cause i can work, but this last month  some time i can't connect with it, i obtained errors like "Lost connection" or "not found the conenction" i wait a 5 min and it turn on again and works again, but i prefer don't stay waiting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using this for learning and testing purposes, I'd suggest using [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc) which simulates Ethereum node. It's fast and runs locally so you won't encounter any connection problems at all.

Comment: With testrpc i can check later  the transactions in etherscan.io ? I don't knwo how it works...

Comment: No, it's a testing tool that runs locally and transactions aren't submitted to a public blockchain. I'd recommend starting with testrpc to develop, test and refactor your contracts and only after they are mature enough publish to public blockchian. Infura it's a good choice for connecting to a public node. Also geth in light mode or parity with pruning are syncing extremely fast. This approach will local testing first will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Ummm ok, and how can i  know if the contact functions works well? For example one transaction of eth or somethign similar liek thsi with the testrpc.

Comment: First, you will have logs from testrpc in console reporting transaction status and consumed gas (similar to what you can get from testrpc). Second, you may write tests to query if the contract states were updated correctly.

Comment: So the contracts can store things, for example a state change, like in the RosptenTest net?

Comment: Yes, every aspect of Ethereum Virtual Machine works exactly the same.

Comment: Ok man, thanks for the explanation i will try it ;)